# Python make list of list contents

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of instances of a particular class Foo, that has a field bar:

```
foo[1..n].bar
```

I'd like to "convert" this to just a list of bar items, so that I have `bar[1..n]`

Sorry for the 1..n notation - I'm just trying to indicate I have an arbitrarily long list.

Be gentle - I'm new to python.

Comment: can you please put your actual list

Comment: no I actually can't.  They are not trivial objects.  foo is a list of modules, and bar is a object that's the same in each one.

Comment: that's okay :) @Marc you might want to check the answers by AnttiHaapala and 7stud. The community believes they have answered well. Look at the votes.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension

```
bar = [ i.bar for i in foo ]
```

Also, list indices in python start from 0, so a list of N elements would have items from `0` to `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

> Be gentle - I'm new to python.

Okay.

> I've got a list of items:
>
> ```
> foo[1..n].bar
> ```

How in the heck is that a list?  A list looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

How does `foo[1..n].bar` fit that format?  Like this?

```
foo[1, 2, 3].bar
```

That's nonsensical.

> I'd like to "convert" this to just a list of bar items, so that I have bar[1..n]

Once again your converted list has to have the format:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

Now the question is what is the conversion factor that transforms your starting list:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3 ]
```

into your transformed list:

```
[obj4, obj5, obj6]
```

????

> can you please put your actual list – Anshuman Dwibhashi  no I
>   actually can't. They are not trivial objects

Well, then post an example with trivial objects.

I sense that you know something about programming in some language, but that this is your first foray into a new language.  The bottom line is: you have to learn the basic syntax in any language before you can speak intelligently about it.  Get a beginning python book and start reading.

Comment: imho this is not an answer, this is a list of questions. you can ask for clarifications adding comments in the OP question.